# The relationships between RDF, RDFS, and OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

Basically, I know that *RDF*, *RDFS*, and *OWL* are used to define the ontologies in order to address the semantics problem in world wide web.

However, these terms make me a bit confused when studying them. This is my conclusion regarding their relationship after reading [this article](https://www.obitko.com/tutorials/ontologies-semantic-web/introduction.html). Please correct me if I get wrong

1. **Resource Description Framework (RDF)**. As its self-explained name, it is just a framework that describes the resources in term of a graph.
2. **RDF Schema (RDFS)**. It is a set of possible *relationships* that could be used in RDF.
3. **Web Ontology Language (OWL)**. It is even an *extended set of possible relationships* for an RDF graph.

Furthermore, what is the status of semantic web technology? Is it still in the research phase, or is it already adopted in production?

Comment: *"I would argue that we could use either OWL or RDFS, not both when creating web semantics."* -> that's wrong and doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @AKSW: could you elaborate on your reasons to help me grasp the point?

Comment: @AKSW, after many thoughts on this topic, I agree with you that this statement makes no sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question might be out of scope for Stackoverflow, but basically:

- RDFS is just some extended [vocabulary for RDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755113/how-are-rdf-and-rdfs-related).
- OWL, on the other hand, is a set of technologies (including a vocabulary) for running reasoners on data sets defined in RDF, to generate new triples.

There are definitely people using Semantic Web Technologies (aka Linked Data) in production, mostly to integrate various data sources. But it definitely hasn't taken off the way HTML or XML have.

Where it's trickled somewhat into the mainstream is with [Facebook's Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) (which is technically not quite RDF unfortunately), Google's [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)  and [schema.org](http://schema.org/).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! For this statement, _"is a set of technologies (including a vocabulary) ..."_, could you provide some examples in your answer?

Answer (score 4):

RDF is a framework, including a data model, a set of syntaxes, and a vocabulary, the latter of which is extended in RDFS to describe relationships of taxonomical structures, such as subclass-superclass relationships, and OWL is a fully-featured ontology language that can describe far more complex relationships, along with constraints on data values. I already explained this on the following page:

[What is the difference between RDF and OWL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740341/what-is-the-difference-between-rdf-and-owl)

Semantic Web technologies are indeed viable and already utilized in a wide range of applications on a global scale by industry giants such as Google as well as governments around the world.